# SSAS Tabular Model: change cases of string value doesn't work

Tags: ssas, powerbi, tabular, ssas-tabular

Just wondering if there is a way that the tabular model can reflect cases changes after I update back-end data. At the moment if I update JOHN SMITH to John Smith in the database, the tabular model doesn't reflect the change even after I do a process clear.

Below is a link to explain how tabular model stores the string value. But it doesn't cover the topic of how to clear the storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/string-storage-and-collation-in-tabular-models?view=sql-server-2017

Appreciate if anyone can provide a solution/workaround.

Cheers

Comment: Running a Process Full on the dimension that was updated should update the casing to user applications.  Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

After a few tests the answer is from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/string-storage-and-collation-in-tabular-models?view=sql-server-2017

In short, e.g. if in the source table we have product name like 'bike', 'BIKE', 'biKE', tabular model will save only the first value. When processing the model, SSAS will evaluate the string value only. Now if we just want to update 'biKE' to 'BIKE', unfortunately because of existence of 'bike', the report still shows product name as 'bike'.

This is a bit interesting. Because when we build data model, we usually denormalise parent-child relationships so obviously we could have duplicated entries. If we have product departments want to display product name in different cases, e.g. Asia department wants to report product name in all upper case, AU department wants to report product name in proper case, we have to build an extra format string.